# How To Make A Swirled Chameleon Tail

Tags: modeling, rigging, curve-modifier

I'm very new to blender and I'm trying to make a chameleon tail. How do you create the swirl shape? I also want to rig it after. What's the best way to go about it? [image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/56396/logarithmic-curve-with-spiralling-cross-section/ https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/230571/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-create-a-pigs-tail/ https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/252268/trying-to-curl-a-snake-tail-stl-file-in-blenderhttps://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/252268/trying-to-curl-a-snake-tail-stl-file-in-blender https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/159890/how-to-taper-a-coil/ https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7088/create-flat-coil

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/49639/how-to-smooth-an-arrayed-object-so-the-breaks-between-objects-are-less-obvious/ https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/230372/snake-defensive-display-animation/